# Datatype Mismatch in criteria expression, Run-time error '2147217913(80040e07)' in SQL VBA

Tags: sql, vba

Getting the datatype mismatch error while opening the record set. here the columns [A/C DOC] & [ITEM CODE] are in general format

```
strQ = "Select Distinct [ITEM CODE] from [Sheet$] WHERE "

strQ = strQ + " [A/C DOC] = '" + Trim(lstDocumentNos(iDocNum)) + "'"

objRecCmd.ActiveConnection = objConn

objRecCmd.CommandText = strQ

objRecordSet_ItemCodes.Open objRecCmd, , adOpenKeyset, adLockOptimistic
```

Comment: Getting the datatype mismatch error in the line :- objRecordSet_ItemCodes.Open objRecCmd, , adOpenKeyset, adLockOptimistic

Comment: a quick thought - is the column name valid? is the forward slash a  permitted character for a column name?  `[A/C DOC]`

Comment: Yes it is , Because it is working in my other queries

Comment: what rdbms are you querying? your'e reading from a sheet on a workbook?

Comment: The driver may have decided that the column you're querying is numeric, so try dropping the quotes around the query value.

Comment: The Column I am using is in generic format also I am reading from a sheet. Here lstDocumentNos(iDocNum) I am giving this as a input to this query

Comment: If you are reading from a sheet do you have a typo in the name? Your table in your quoted code is `[Sheet$]` - do you mean that to be `[Sheet1$]` or something?

Comment: Here [Sheet] is the sheet name of excel file from where we are reading the data. It is fixed, No Typo

Comment: Please include the variable declarations in your code example

Comment: Did you try dropping the quotes around the value?

Comment: These are the declaration variablePrivate Function Process_File(ByVal strFilePath As String, ByVal strDocumentNo As String)


Dim objConn As Object
Dim objRecordSet As Object
Dim objRecCmd As Object
Dim objRecCmd_Update As Object
Dim strPTaxableValue As String
Dim strNTaxableValue As String
Dim strTaxableValue As String
Dim strNIQuantity As Double
Dim strNITotal As Double
Dim objRecordSet_ItemCodes As Object
Dim objRecordSet_Temp As Object
Dim strLinesToBeDeleted As String